# Create type of the column in the List SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I have a class **CategoryItem**.

```
public CategoryItem()
        {
            Title = string.Empty;
            Description = string.Empty;
            TitleSort = string.Empty;
            Index = 0;
            CategoryIDTintuc = 0;
            CategoryAllID = string.Empty;
            PageUrl = string.Empty;
            Parent = new SPFieldLookupValue();
            ListFileAttach = new List<FileAttach>();
            ModerationStatus = SPModerationStatusType.Pending;
            IsShow = true;
        }
```

And use Caml query code.

```
   if (SpListProcess.EnableModeration)
        {
           stbQuery.Append("<And>");
           stbQuery.Append("<Eq>");
           stbQuery.Append("<FieldRefName=\"_ModerationStatus\" />");
           stbQuery.Append("<Value Type=\"ModStat\">Approved</Value>");
           stbQuery.Append("</Eq>");
         }
           stbQuery.Append("<Eq>");
           stbQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name=\"IsShow\" />");
           stbQuery.Append("<Value Type=\"Boolean\">1</Value>");
           stbQuery.Append("                </Eq>");

    if (SpListProcess.EnableModeration)
          {
           stbQuery.Append("</And>");
          }
           stbQuery.Append("</Where>");
```

I need to create List for CategoryItem and Caml query code, I don't know how to create column for "ModerationStatus" and "IsShow". Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create **Choice field type column** using below code:

```
string fieldStatusName = list.Fields.Add("Status", SPFieldType.Choice, false);
SPFieldChoice fieldStatus = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldStatusName);
string[] activityTypes = { "Active", "Closed" };
fieldStatus.Choices.AddRange(activityTypes);
fieldStatus.DefaultValue = "Active";
fieldStatus.Update();
```

For **Boolean field type column** try below code:

```
string fieldInternalName = list.Fields.Add("fieldname", SPFieldType.Boolean, false);
```

You can get more info about creating columns and Lists from below references:

- https://aleemsheikh.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/creating-list-fields-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2010-2/
- http://burnignorance.com/sharepoint-tips-and-hacks/add-columns-fields-programmatically-to-a-sharepoint-list/
- http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-columns-site-columns-or-content-types

Answer (score 0):

(Document Library Settings -> Versioning Settings -> Draft Item Security) Can active Approval Status(_ModerationStatus).

Comment: Is this an answer or an edit to your question? It is not clear

Comment: It is answer for my question. :)